# Targeting help! Trying to scrape two points of data using simple_html_dom

Tags: php, html, dom, web-scraping

I have hit yet another barrier with my project, I am using simple_html_dom and cannot seem to be able to target these two points of data. I am pulling the data from https://survivetheark.com/index.php?/forums/topic/49912-vote-on-maps/

Here is the code I have put together to get the number on the right, but cannot seem to be able to even target that one.

```
<?php
include 'simple_html_dom.php';

$html = file_get_contents('https://survivetheark.com/index.php?/forums/topic/49912-vote-on-maps/'); 
$yourDesiredContent = $html->find('us.ipsList_reset.cPollList_choices li',8);
echo $yourDesiredContent;
?>
```

[image: The two points of data i am trying to collect]

Thank you!

Comment: try this .. updated ends

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
include 'simple_html_dom.php';

$html = file_get_html('https://survivetheark.com/index.php?/forums/topic/49912-vote-on-maps/');

$cPollVoteBar = $html->find('ul.cPollList_choices',0)->find('li.ipsGrid',7)->find('div.ipsGrid_span7',0)->find('span.cPollVoteBar',0)->find('span',0);

$yourDesiredContent = $cPollVoteBar->data-votes;

?>
```

this will solve your problem, if not let me know error because i haven't checked it.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, I am getting this error though:

[15-Apr-2016 14:59:54 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function find() on a non-object in /home/travisohdell1/public_html/JL_TwitchStatus/votecount/votecounter.php on line 5